# Set or Assign ID or REL inside PHP code

Tags: php, html-table

I want to set or assign id / rel inside my table code, take a look on my code below this so every table td has id and rel so I can give statement and manipulate the date within the jQuery, any helps will be much more appreciated:

```
function printdata()
{
    if(is_array($_SESSION['chart']))
    {
    echo "Here's your chart" . "<br>";
    $max = count($_SESSION['chart']);  
    $th1 = "<th>" . "No" . "</th>";
    $th2 = "<th>" . "Nama Barang" . "</th>";
    $th3 = "<th>" . "Harga Barang" . "</th>";
    $th4 = "<th>" . "Stok Barang" . "</th>";
    echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo $th1 ;
    echo $th2;
    echo $th3;
    echo $th4;
    echo "</tr>";
    for ($indexo = 0; $indexo < $max; $indexo++) {
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>" . $indexo."</td>";
       echo "<td >" . $_SESSION['chart'][$indexo]['namabarang']."</td>";
       //i want to assign td rel inside of this echo 
       echo "<td>" . $_SESSION['chart'][$indexo]['hargabarang']."</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $_SESSION['chart'][$indexo]['stokbarang']."</td>";
       echo " <td><button id=".$indexo." name=\"button\">Edit</button></td>";
       echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    }else
    {
        echo "Chart is still Empty";
    }
}
```

Comment: can't understand exactly the problem,, sorry

Comment: I want to assign dynamically on each row table I've created

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<table border=1 id=\"{$some_php_variable_with_an_id_value_in_it}\">"
```

Answer (score 0):

first your code is too much line over there, that is no need to do such as that, it can be more simple to build some output with the same result, here may be could to help ya

```
function printdata(){
    if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
        echo "Here's Your Chart ".count($_SESSION['cart'])."<br />";
        echo '<table><tr>th>No</th><th>Nama Barang</th><th>Harga Barang</th><th>Stok Barang</th><th>Action</th></tr>';
        for($indexo =0; $indexp < count($_SESSION['cart']); $indexo++){
            echo "<tr>
                <td id=".$indexo.">".$indexo."</td>
                <td id=".$_SESSION['chart'][$indexo]['namabarang'].">".$_SESSION['chart'][$indexo]['namabarang']."<td>
                <td id=".$_SESSION['chart'][$indexo]['hargabarang'].">".$_SESSION['chart'][$indexo]['hargabarang']."<td>
                <td id="$_SESSION['chart'][$indexo]['stokbarang']">".$_SESSION['chart'][$indexo]['stokbarang']."<td>
                <td><button id=".$indexo." name=\"button\">Edit</button></td>
            </tr>";
        }
    }else{
         echo "Chart is still Empty";
    }
}
```

You can Change `<td id=".$indexo.">` to what ever you want to, seems like the other, `id` or `rel` will be the same implementation i guest